# How to calculate hamming distance between 1d and 2d array without loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

A is a 1d array with shape 100, B is a 2d array with shape (50000, 100). I want to calculate hamming distance between A and B, and get an array X with shape 50000.

I can do it with a loop:

```
for i in range(50000):
    X[i] = np.count_nonzero(A != B[j,:])
```

I'd like to know can I skip the loop or do something to make it faster?

Comment: `(A != B).sum(axis=1)` ?

Comment: Thanks, you are right!@Julien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly compare `A` and `B` with `A != B`, which will broadcast due to the different number of dimensions `A` and `B` have, and then you can use `np.count_nonzero` per row with `axis=1`:

```
np.count_nonzero(A != B, axis=1)
```

---

```
A = np.array([1,2])
B = np.array([[1,2],[3,2],[1,3],[2,4]])

np.count_nonzero(A != B, axis=1)
# array([0, 1, 1, 2])
```